# access control id name from android emulator to c# code (winforms)

Tags: c#, android

I want to run a program in c# and try to access id of application run in android emulator. I have use Eneter Messaging Framework but it will not provide id of control. Anyone knows how to access control information in c# code when user clicks on any control in android emulator. I am beginner